# Dynamically setting the range for sorting in Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I recorded a macro for sorting. I want to replace he hardcoded row count so that this macro can be used anywhere

```
.SetRange ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

this part of the code throws VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, just a note this will work if the range's top left cell is A1.

`.SetRange Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))`